# How to force a string to sort to bottom in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I could have sworn that Crystal Reports used to sort strings beginning with a space to the bottom. For example, the strings " Amsterdam", "Belfast", and "Cancun" would be sorted as:

```
Belfast
Cancun
 Amsterdam
```

This [thread](http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=12653) seems to confirm that.

However, now I'm using CR 2008 SP3 and it's being sorted to the top, as:

```
 Amsterdam
Belfast
Cancun
```

I have tried all sorts of special and control characters and everything is sorting to the top. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about inserting another sorting level, using a formula `CitySort:`

```
If {City} = " Amsterdam" Then 1 Else 0
```

Comment: That would work. What I ended up doing was just prepending "zzz" to the ones I wanted sorted to the bottom and then display the original field to avoid adding another group level. My main concern, though, was that CR changed the sort order for non-alphanumeric string characters... I have a feeling I've got broken reports floating around now.

Comment: Between XI and 2008, you're thinking?

Comment: Or between Service Packs for 2008? Who knows, I may be imagining things.

Comment: The new behavior is consistent with ASCII/Unicode: the designers of ASCII placed the space character before the letters and numbers in order to simplify sorting. Crystal's sort is case-insensitive, so it doesn't follow ASCII ordering exactly, but putting a space first is more consistent. For what it's worth, most often I use `@` or `!` to sort entries to the top of a list and `Ω` for the bottom. I can't remember whether I've used them in Crystal.